# Guest access is disabled in oracle bi publisher

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

I've connected through bi publisher with sys account which have admin privilage, but I'm not be able to define guest folder name, because allow guest access check box and guest folder name are disabled.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Administration > Server Configuration (under system maintenance) then change catalog type to "Oracle BI Publisher - File System" and put your config dir in Path:

*${xdo.server.config.dir}/repository*

Restart Bi Publisher.
Guest will be available after restart.

Comment: Thank you, works great. but my reports is not availble after change.